# Kendo-grid AngularJs: put DataSource in HTML tag

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

There is a way to put the `DataSource` as html tag? for example:

```
<kendo-grid dataSource.data="SomeDataFrom$Scope" options="GridOptions"></kendo-grid>
```

My problem: I'm in the loop of `ng-repeat` and for each iteration I want to produce kendo grid with different data. This is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid options="GridOptions" ??="PricesPerGroup"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `k-data-source` attribute:

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid k-data-source="PricesPerGroup"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

If you must use `k-options` then use a $scope function which will create the options:

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions(PricesPerGroup)"></kendo-grid>
</div>

$scope.gridOptions = function(data) {
   return {
     dataSource: {
        data: data
     }
   };
};
```

Comment: While using the above format HTML Formatting text not supporting, could you help me to overcome from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid options="GridOptions" dataSource.data="PricesPerGroup"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```